# Win RT how to place button in specific coordinates?

Tags: button, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, coordinates

I am trying to place a button in a particular x and y values.Is it possible in metro c#(windows store app).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two main options and one less obvious.

1. If your button is in in a `Canvas` panel - you can set `Canvas.X` and `Canvas.Y` attached properties on the button to the desired values.
2. If your button is in the default 1x1 cell `Grid` - you can set `HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,20,0,0"` where 10 and 20 are the x and y values.
3. If you want to animate the coordinates (not typical with a button, but who am I to judge) - it's best to use a `RenderTransform` to position it. You'd set it's base coordinates to 0,0 using either of the two former methods, set the `RenderTransform` to say `TranslateTransform` and set the transform's `X` and `Y` properties to the desired values. The idea is that properties of a `RenderTransform` can be smoothly animated while `Canvas.X/Y` or `Margin` properties can't because they affect the layout and layout calculations are slow.

Comment: Perhaps it's a worthwhile comment to add: should you do this in an environment where your app could be resized or rotated at any moment? 99% of the time, no.